# Large set of data in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, abstract-class, qabstractlistmodel

I am trying to add large sets of data in QTableView. As there is huge set of data, in order to avoid freezing the application, I am trying to use a `QAbstractTableModel` to not showthe whole dataset immediately, but only what is necessary. Based on the QT example for this ([HERE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html)), I have the following class:
**FileListModel.cpp**

```
#include "filelistmodel.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPalette>
#include "qdebug.h"

FileListModel::FileListModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent), fileCount(0) //edit
{}

int FileListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : fileCount;
}

QVariant FileListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (index.row() >= fileList.size() || index.row() < 0)
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return fileList.at(index.row());
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool FileListModel::canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (fileCount < fileList.size());
}
int FileListModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : colCount;
}
void FileListModel::fetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if (parent.isValid())
    {
        return;
    }
    int remainder = fileList.size() - fileCount;
    int itemsToFetch = qMin(100, remainder);

    if (itemsToFetch <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), fileCount, fileCount + itemsToFetch - 1);
    qDebug()<< "Qmodelindex "<< QModelIndex()<< "filecount "<< fileCount <<"filecount + itemtofetch "<<fileCount + itemsToFetch - 1;
    fileCount += itemsToFetch;

    endInsertRows();
}
void FileListModel::setColumnNumber(const int x) //edit
{
    colCount = x;
}
void FileListModel::setDataToList(const QList<float> &data)
{
    beginResetModel();
    fileList = data;
    fileCount = 0;
    endResetModel();
}
```

**FileListModel.h**

```
#ifndef FILELISTMODEL_H
#define FILELISTMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QStringList>

class FileListModel : public QAbstractTableModel //edit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FileListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override; //edit
    void setColumnNumber(const int );

public slots:
    void setDataToList(const QList<float>&);

protected:
    bool canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    void fetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) override;

private:
    QList<float> fileList;
    int fileCount;
int colCount;//edit
};

#endif // FILELISTMODEL_H
```

In my window, I have a `QTableView` and 5 `QList<float>`, each representing a column.
I proceed this way to add the data in my QTableView:

```
FileListModel *model=new FileListModel(this);
model->setColumnNumber(5); //edit

model->setDataToList(list1);
model->setDataToList(list2);
model->setDataToList(list3);
model->setDataToList(list4);
model->setDataToList(list5);

tableview->setModel(model)
```

However, the last list added (`list5`) replace the previous one and I have only the same text in all the columns. I am aware that I need to write the needed code to add columns. But to be honest, I am not knowing very well the `QAbstract` classes, and have no idea how to proceed. I would be grateful if you could provide me some hints or an example on how to modify my code in order to add columns in my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to proceed by storing my data in a QList>.
Please find below a working code that can probably be improved:

CPP FILE

```
#include "filelistmodel.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPalette>
#include "qdebug.h"

FileListModel::FileListModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent), rowNumber(0)
{}

int FileListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : rowNumber;
}

int FileListModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return parent.isValid() ? 0 : colNumber;
}

void FileListModel::setColumnNumber(const int x)
{
    colNumber = x;
}

QVariant FileListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (index.row() >= fileList[0].size() || index.row() < 0)
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return fileList[index.column()][index.row()];
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool FileListModel::canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (rowNumber < fileList[0].size());
}

void FileListModel::fetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if (parent.isValid())
    {
        return;
    }
    int remainder = fileList[0].size() - rowNumber;
    int itemsToFetch = qMin(100, remainder);

    if (itemsToFetch <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowNumber, rowNumber + itemsToFetch - 1);

    rowNumber += itemsToFetch;

    endInsertRows();
}

void FileListModel::setDataToTable(const QList<QList<float>> &data)
{
    beginResetModel();
    fileList = data;
    rowNumber = 0;
    endResetModel();
}
```

H FILE

```
#ifndef FILELISTMODEL_H
#define FILELISTMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>

class FileListModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FileListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    void setColumnNumber(const int );
    void setDataToTable(const QList<QList<float>>&);

protected:
    bool canFetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    void fetchMore(const QModelIndex &parent) override;

private:
    QList<QList<float>> fileList;
    int rowNumber;
    int colNumber;
};

#endif // FILELISTMODEL_H
```

BUILDING MODEL

```
FileListModel *pModel =new FileListModel(this);
QList<QList<float>> a;
pModel->setColumnNumber(5);
a.append(qlist1);
a.append(qlist2);
a.append(qlist3);
a.append(qlist4);
a.append(qlist5);
pModel->setDataToTable(a);
```